# Stored Procedures Best Practices

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm just learning stored procedures and have read a fair bit on the topic (so apologies for repeating) but haven't found a definitive answer for a couple of suggested best practices as follows:

1. `SET XACT_ABORT ON` = does a try/catch block replace this? [And is rollback even necessary for simple non-nested stored procedures?]
2. For stored procedures without return values (such as inserts) what if anything should I return to the caller (obviously an error if fail but what if succeed, especially when using `SET NOCOUNT ON`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What to return will depend on your business needs. In general, we only return errors, but other companies/processes have different needs.

Sometimes we use output parameters to send some values back that might be used later in a long complicated process that executes many stored procs. This is especially true if you have a lot of conditional logic to tell what other procs to run under the current set of circumstances.

Be clear though, return should return error or success information, output should return actual data (such as a person id) that you intend to do something with later in the process or display in the app.  If you have more than a scalar value to return to the calling process, use a select instead of an output variable. Don't try to use Return to return anything other than status of the run and don't try to use output to return multiple records.

One thing you should consider if you decide to handle rollbacks with Try Catch and do explicit steps, if you have put information into a table variable then that is not rolled back but any data inserted into a regular table or a temp table would be. That means if you want to log your steps or errors, you should but them in a table variable, so they can be inserted into the logging table after the commit or rollback.

If you are going to write anything complex at all with lots of steps and variables, do yourself a favor and add an @test input variable, so that you can run it in a test mode (and rollback) and do tests at key points to see what your variable values or the results of a select that insert statement might use, etc, would be. This will help tremendously in finding out exactly what information you tried to insert when the insert step fails. If you spend an extra hour or so doing this up front you will save hundreds of hours figuring out why the proc errored later on.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer to Question 1:**

When `SET XACT_ABORT` is set to `ON` it rolls back the transaction as soon as an error occurs, if you like to control this behavior, (you decide when to rollback and when not to, which I personally prefer), simply use `TRY..CATCH` blocks and keep the control of raising an error in your own hands, Try to do something in TRY BLOCK if something goes wrong control jumps to Catch block, Rollback the transaction there explicitly , do other error logging and come out tada.....

**Answer to Question 2:**

Use `OUTPUT` parameters to return values like `@SuccessStatus`and if and error occurred use another output parameter to return some sort of error message etc, OUTPUT parameters are your friend, use them wisely.